# Is there any way to prevent my bootsrap cards from getting nested by a django for loop?

Tags: django, user-interface, bootstrap-4

When I run this, it nests the cards within each other as such:

[image: cards nested within each other]

```
{% for task in tasks %}
<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ task.name }}</h5>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card-body ">
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"> Date due: {{ task.date }}. </h6>
    <p class="card-text"> {{ task.description }}</p>
  </div>

  {% empty %}
  
  <h4> Good to go!No tasks yet </h4>
</div>
<br/><br/> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What kind of design do you want? do you want three card in one row, then again three in further row, something like that?

Answer (score 1):

As isherwood rightly suggested, use spacing classes instead.

You can start with a min margin value such as `m-2`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card text-center m-2">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ task.name }}</h5>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card-body ">
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"> Date due: {{ task.date }}. </h6>
    <p class="card-text"> {{ task.description }}</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card text-center m-2">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ task.name }}</h5>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card-body ">
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"> Date due: {{ task.date }}. </h6>
    <p class="card-text"> {{ task.description }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This gives you a size 2 (1.5rem) margin on four sides. As shown in the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing/), you can control all sides individually as needed.

Comment: It doesn't work, it still places the next card within the parent card

Comment: @NajeebYusufLawal see updated answer based on isherwood's correction.